# Can I use sounds from UT2004?

Tags: copyright, sound-effects

What if I use some sounds from the game Unreal Tournament 2004? I can export them from `.uax` archives via **UnrealED** tool into `.wav` files. I could (and very would like to) import them into my game I am developing and use them there.

But is that right thing to do accoring to the copyright laws? Could Epic Games, I don't know, sue me for that? Or they can't unless I make the game shareware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All assets, including, but not limited to, sounds in Unreal Tournament 2004 are the property of Epic Games. Unless you obtain explicit permission you cannot use any asset from UT2004 in other games. I do believe you are allowed to use the assets to build maps and mods for UT2004, as long as the mods is not sold for money. You should consult a lawyer to be sure!

A partial [solution is to get a commercial license for the Unreal Development Kit](https://forums.epicgames.com/threads/721465-Commercial-Licensing-Terms-Update-Use-UDK-assets!) after which you can use all asset bundled with it. However, I do not know if the UDK includes all assets from UT2004.

Comment: Okay, but what if I modulate and mix a copyrighted sound? Can I do that?

Comment: Modifying something that is copyright protected does not remove the copyright.